# Android RecyclerView MVVM where to update Adapter with notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Where should I call any form of `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter? The data source is populated asynchronously because I fetch the data from the web.

The adapter belongs to the view. However the data source of the adapter belongs to the viewmodel. The viewmodel should not have a reference to the view.

The only way of updating my adapter I can think of is using a broadcast receiver and I don't think that is a recommended solution as well.

MyFragment.kt

```
override fun onViewCreated(...) {
    //...
    recyclerView.adapter = myItemAdapter
}
```

MyViewModel.kt

```
private val _myItems = mutableListOf<Item>()
val myItems: List<Item> = _myItems 

private fun someMethod() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _myItems.addAll(itemsRepository.getSomeItems())
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I don't want to encapsulate the data source in a `LiveData` and observe it for changes in the view, because the data source is really just initialized once and never updated again. Is there another way of doing it or do I have to use `LiveData`?

Answer (score 0):

declare `_myItems` by MutableLiveData

`val _myItems =  MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item1>>()`

and observe it in fragment

```
viewModel._myItems.observe(this, Observer { itemss ->
    myItemAdapter.set(items)
    myItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: Okay, I should have said that I thought about this as well. I don't really want to make it LiveData and observe it because I feel like that's much overhead and confusing since the data source is really only initialized once and never updated again.

Comment: @SaPropper if you don't use LiveData or observe, you don't need MVVM

Comment: I use it for data that changes (more than once)... But I guess you're right: observers are the only way